# How to tell client value of client_max_body_size

Tags: nginx

I want to show max size user can upload to user.

Are there any features such as nginx returns value of `client_max_body_size` when client send a request that contains header `GET_MAX_BODY_SIZE`?

Comment: What have you tried already that did not work?

Comment: nothing. I don't know what I should try.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible to return a header with the maximum size allowed, however, it is not possible to capture this value dynamically. In this case you will have to enter the value in the header manually.

The change is more or less like this.

```
location ~ \.php$ {
        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.1-fpm.sock;

        # Modification here
        if ($http_x_get_max_body_size) {
                add_header "Client-Max-Body-Size" "300M";
        }
}
```

This way you can use return a value in the "response header"

```
curl -I -H "X-GET-MAX-BODY-SIZE: get" http://example.com

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx/1.10.3 (Ubuntu)
Date: Wed, 20 Dec 2017 01:44:38 GMT
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Connection: keep-alive
Client-Max-Body-Size: 300M

/* ******************************************************** */

curl -I http://example.com

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx/1.10.3 (Ubuntu)
Date: Wed, 20 Dec 2017 01:45:35 GMT
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Connection: keep-alive
```